# Regex to replace part of the string with spaces

Tags: java, regex

It seems simple, but I can't get it work.

I have a string which look like 'NNDDDDDAAAA', where 'N' is non digit, 'D' is digit, and 'A' is anything. I need to replace each A with a space character. Number of 'N's, 'D's, and 'A's in an input string is always different.

I know how to do it with two expressions. I can split a string in to two, and then replace everything in second group with spaces. Like this

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\D+\\d+)(.+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        return matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2).replaceAll(".", " ");
    }
```

But I was wondering if it is possible with a single regex expression.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between the 'A's and the others? Do 'A's always come after the 'D's?

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the last "D" and the first "A"? Is the group of "A"s guaranteed not to be a "D" type character?

Comment: Curtis Tasker is correct, first A after NNDDDD is always N, the rest is anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for a regex, but why do you even need a regex for this? How about:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
for (int i = sb.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (Character.isDigit(sb.charAt(i)))
        break;
    sb.setCharAt(i, ' ');
}
String output = sb.toString();
```

You might find [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html) interesting. Of course, the above code assumes there will be at least one digit in the string - all characters following the last digit are converted to spaces. If there are no digits, every character is converted to a space.

Comment: I think you are right. 

I was refactoring some old code which has multiple loops and indexOf()/substring() and I thought it could be done with a simple regex. Didn't even think about cleaning up the old logic. I think your approach would be the most efficient for this task.  
Thanks for thinking outside the box, i.e. my initial requirements.

Comment: Your code assumes that the AAA portion will be non-digits.  This is contrary to the problem description, which says that A will be 'anything', which could include digits.

Comment: Well then, the solution can be slightly adapted to locate the point where a digit is followed by a non-digit. It still ends up being simpler than using regexes where they're not really necessary.

Comment: yes, I had to add additional logic to find the point where digits are allowed. Still pretty simple

Answer (score 3):

Given your description, I'm assuming that after the `NNDDDDD` portion, the first `A` will actually be a `N` rather than an `A`, since otherwise there's no solid boundary between the `DDDDD` and `AAAA` portions.

So, your string actually looks like `NNDDDDDNAAA`, and you want to replace the `NAAA` portion with spaces.  Given this, the regex can be rewritten as such: `(\\D+\\d+)(\\D.+)`

Positive lookbehind in Java requires a fixed length pattern; You can't use the `+` or `*` patterns. You can instead use the curly braces and specify a maximum length. For instance, you can use `{1,9}` in place of each `+`, and it will match between 1 and 9 characters: `(?<=\\D{1,9}\\d{1,9})(\\D.+)`

The only problem here is you're matching the NAAA sequence as a single match, so using `"NNNDDDDNAAA".replaceAll("(?<=\\D{1,9}\\d{1,9})(\\D.+)", " ")` will result in replacing the entire `NAAA` sequence with a single space, rather than multiple spaces.

You could take the beginning delimiter of the match, and the string length, and use that to append the correct number of spaces, but I don't see the point.  I think you're better off with your original solution;   Its simple and easy to follow.

If you're looking for a little extra speed, you could compile your Pattern outside the function, and use StringBuilder or StringBuffer to create your output.  If you're building a large String out of all these NNDDDDDAAAAA elements, work entirely in StringBuilder until you're done appending.

```
class Test {

public static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+\\d+)(\\D.+)");

public static StringBuffer replace( String input ) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Test.p.matcher(input);
    if( m.matches() )
        output.append( m.group(1) ).append( m.group(2).replaceAll("."," ") );

    return output;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = args[0];
    long startTime;

    StringBuffer tests = new StringBuffer();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            tests.append( "Input -> Output: '" );
            tests.append( input );
            tests.append( "' -> '" );
            tests.append( Test.replace( input ) );
            tests.append( "'\n" );
        }
    System.out.println( tests.toString() );
    System.out.println( "\n" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
}

}
```

**Update:**
I wrote a quick iterative solution, and ran some random data through both.  The iterative solution is around 4-5x faster.

```
public static StringBuffer replace( String input )
{
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    boolean second = false, third = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ )
    {
        if( !second && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) )
            second = true;

        if( second && !third && Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i)) )
            third = true;

        if( second && third )
            output.append( ' ' );
        else
            output.append( input.charAt(i) );

    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by nondigit vs anything?

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]`
matches everything that is **not** a letter or digit.

you would want to replace anything that gets matched by the above regex with a space.

is this what you were talking about?

Comment: Don't you mean /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g   ?

Comment: that would delete the "anything" matches, I just wanted to throw the regex up that actually matches "anything"  I will take the slashes out to clear things up.  Thanks.

Comment: 'anything' means anything, i.e. letters, digits, whitespace. 

I want replace each occurrence with a space. For instance, 'AA12345d4 %' would be replaced with 'AA12345    ' (four spaces at the end)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use positive look behind to match the N's and D's then use a normal match for the A's.

Not sure of the positive look behind grammar in Java, but some article on [Java regex with look behind](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/PositiveLookbehind1.htm)

Comment: I was just about to post that ... honest! Don't know if you are allowed to have a variable length look behind pattern though eg (?<=\D+)

Comment: Not sure, about the Java regex: I've read some articles talking about pos/neg look ahead/behind restrictions in the three major variants of regex engines and the main take away I had was the the .Net regex could do the good stuff, but sometimes just because it can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Here's a nice description of various engines' support for look behind: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind

Comment: No, in general they do not allow variable-width look behind. "(?<=\D+)" is allowed because it is equivalent to the fixed-width look behind "(?<=\D)"

Comment: And in any case, even if a look behind worked, it would not solve the OP's problem, which is to replace every character in the matched group with a space. There is no replacement string that will allow you to perform "replace this with a string of spaces of the same length".